# Angular 4 with Auth0 JWT branch v1.0

Tags: angular

I follow the code that is made available via the website 
https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/tree/v1.0

The trouble is with the code below is , it needs to be in the app.module.ts. This piece of code is initialized before the login page is presented, so I will always have an empty 'access_token'.  Can someone enlighten me on how to get this to work after the login is authenticated?  Thank you.

```
JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: () => {
          return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
        },
        whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:3001']
      }
    })
```

Comment: All that does is provide a function for `tokenGetter` so that the module knows how to get the token. It's not actually being invoked

Comment: If I put a console.log tokenGetter: () => { console.log('I am here');
          return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
        } it fires the console log, and on subsequent http.get to my API server it is passing in empty token.

Comment: If you check in the browser, has it actually set the token in localStorage? And are you using `httpClient` as opposed to `http`?

Comment: the Auth0 JWT branch v1.0 uses HttpClient by default.

Comment: Yes, but when you make your http requests, are you making sure to use http client?

Comment: yes,  I am use httpClient from '@angular/common/http' on all my http get/post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159321/discussion-between-user184994-and-albertk).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the pointers.  I have to convert the lambda to a function otherwise it would not compile for production (ng build --prod).

Also my login function to get the token from the API server also needs to be a promise.

// Authenticate/Login class.

```
public  isLogin(userkey: string, password: string ): Promise<boolean> {
        const logindata = new LoginData();
        logindata.UserKey = userkey;
        logindata.Password = password;


        console.log('Before Get Token');
         const retpromise =   this.http.post<TokenData>(`${this.Url}/login`, logindata, {headers: this.getHeader()})
         .map(m => {
                     console.log('Got Token Data');
                     localStorage.setItem('token', m.token);
                     return true;
        })
       .toPromise();
       return retpromise;
```

// app.module.ts

```
export function getToken(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
}

@ngModule({
declarations: [...],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
HttpClientModule,
JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: getToken
        },
        whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:3001']
      }
    })
}
],
bootstrap:[AppComponent])
```